# Node. js vs Io.js

Tags: node.js

Sou nova por aqui e  gostaria de saber mais sobre o `Node.js` e o `Io.js`. Andei pesquisando sobre os dois e vi que o `node.js` é um ambiente de execução para auxiliar na escrita de programas em JavaScript, sendo multiplataforma  e que utiliza um paradigma de orientação a eventos com um sistema de I/O não bloqueando que consegue lidar melhor com aplicações em tempo real, com um grande número de conexões simultâneas. Sua arquitetura propõe a utilização de uma única thread ativada por evento, o que otimiza a utilização de recursos em aplicações em tempo real (como chat, transações bancárias,  etc). Uma das desvantagens é que  aplicações que utilizam banco de dados relacionais, acabam sendo pouco suportadas em Node, pois acabam não aproveitando o máximo potencial de suas vantagens.

- Gostaria de saber, quais são outras desvantagens apresentadas pelo Node.js?

Não consegui encontrar muita informação sobre o `Io.js` somente que assim como o `Node.js` ele é uma plataforma JavaScript construída no Chrome’s V8 runtime e utiliza o conceito de modelo de governança aberto no seu desenvolvimento.

- Gostaria de saber quais as vantagens e desvantagens apresentadas pelo Io.js?
- Em quais aplicações é recomendável a utilização do Io.js?
- E em quais não são recomendável?
- Quais as principais diferenças entre Node.js e Io.js?
- Quando compensa mais usar o Io.js do que o Node.js?

Comment: Olá Valeria! A tua pergunta tem resposta nessa outra que indiquei. Basicamente o `io.js` foi uma versão rebelde, paralela, do Node.js. Mas há uns tempos a zanga acabou e voltaram a juntar-se. Agora só há Node.js.